# Call a Python Method from C# (without IronPython)

Tags: c#, python

How would I call a function in a python script from my c# method? (without IronPython)

in hello.py

```
def hello_world(msg):
    print msg
```

in test.cs

```
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo ();
        start.FileName = "hello.py";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", arg);
        start.UseShellExecute = true;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {

        }
```

Comment: So you're saying you've tried this and it's not working?  What error message(s) do you get, from what source(s)?

Comment: Try putting the 'python.exe' as the `FileName` and the hello.py as an argument. (the exact name of the exe will of course depend on the version of python you have installed)

Comment: Also, a note from MSDN: "You must set UseShellExecute to false if you want to set RedirectStandardOutput to true. Otherwise, reading from the StandardOutput stream throws an exception." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The OS is probably not resolving the file association properly, so it doesn't know how to execute the .py file.

Instead, try putting the 'python.exe' as the FileName and the hello.py as an argument. The exact name of the exe will of course depend on the version of python you have installed.

As an example:

```
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo ();
    start.FileName = @"c:\python\python27.exe";
    start.Arguments = string.Format("hello.py {0}", arg);
    start.UseShellExecute = true;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {

    }
```

(In the above example, you must of course substitute the full path of your python executable to make it work)